# DART (XGBoost package): using rate_drop with skip_drop

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, boosting

In the XGBoost package, the DART regressor allows you to specify two parameters that are not inherited from the standard XGBoost regressor: rate_drop and skip_drop. My question is, isn't any combination of values for rate_drop and skip_drop equivalent to just setting a certain value of rate_drop?

For example, if I set rate_drop=.5 and skip_drop=.5, would this just be equivalent to my setting rate_drop=.25?